# Difference between has_perm and has_module_perms

Tags: django

While creating a custom user model I saw these two methods:

1. `has_perm()`
2. `has_module_perms()`

Also I encountered these two methods when I tried to create Custom Permsion in django-rest-framework.

Could someone please help me understand what they are and exactly where or how can I use them?

Answer (score 3):

These methods are covered in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#methods).

[`has_perm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm) checks whether the user has a specific permission, for example:

```
user.has_perm('polls.can_vote')
```

[`has_module_perm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_module_perms) checks whether the user has *any* permissions for that app, for example:

```
user.has_module_perm('polls')
```

Comment: My issue is the docs don't suggest a use case for this functionality, and I'm struggling to think of one, which makes me feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: @odigity The django admin calls `has_module_perm` for each installed app, to decide whether or not to show it on the admin index page (http://localhost:8000/admin by default)